# toggle a function that sets the setinterval on

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I can add a call to function soapFlow() manually in 20 places. But I would rather toggle a function that sets the setinterval on and **leaves** on:

```
<li onclick="pre_reg_on();" >auto-reg</li>

function greet() {setInterval(soapFlow, 5000);}

function pre_reg_on () {greet();}
```

It should call function greet() every 5 seconds, but it only calls it once.

Comment: how do you know it only calls it once? as far as I can see, the code would start a new interval every time that `li` is clicked

Comment: can you explain your question in a bit more detail? i'm a little confused as to what your question is and what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Glad to. I wrote a pre-reg mobile app that sends ID's to a server. On load the main program html and js needs to be updated and last week's player data erased. But this also erases the new incoming pre-reg player data due to setinterval reading function soapFlow() and adding the new pre-regs automatically. Else I would just set setInterval(soapFlow, 5000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInterval()` should be called outside of the function you want it execute from it. Also to avoid multiple timers, you should always clear previous timers before setting a new one:

```js
function greet() {
  console.log("greet() executed " + Date())
}

function pre_reg_on() {
  stopInterval();
  greet(); //execute imediately
  greet.interval = setInterval(greet, 5000);
}

function stopInterval()
{
  if (!greet.interval)
    return;

  clearInterval(greet.interval); // make sure clear previous interval;
  console.log("timer stopped " + Date());
  delete greet.interval;
}
```

```html
<li onclick="pre_reg_on();">auto-reg</li>
<li onclick="stopInterval();">stop</li>
```

Comment: Shouldn't greet() also include setInterval(soapFlow, 5000);

Comment: I don't know what `soapFlow` is, hens it was removed. Your question was about executing `greet()` every 5 seconds, the example does exactly that.